# How to write PCAP capture file header?

Tags: c++, logging, wireshark, pcap, libpcap

Without using libpcap I am trying to write a log file that adheres to the pcap file format ([format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat)). This file needs to be readable by WireShark. So far I've written this in C++:

```
struct pcapFileHeader {
    uint32_t magic_number;   /* magic number */
    uint16_t version_major;  /* major version number */
    uint16_t version_minor;  /* minor version number */
    int16_t  thiszone;       /* GMT to local correction */
    uint32_t sigfigs;        /* accuracy of timestamps */
    uint32_t snaplen;        /* max length of captured packets, in octets */
    uint32_t network;        /* data link type */
};

ofstream fileout;
fileout.open("file.pcap", ios::trunc);

pcapFileHeader fileHeader;
fileHeader.magic_number = 0xa1b2c3d4;
fileHeader.version_major = 2;
fileHeader.version_minor = 4;
fileHeader.thiszone = 0;
fileHeader.sigfigs = 0;
fileHeader.snaplen = 65535; //(2^16)
fileHeader.network = 1;     //Ethernet

fileout <<  fileHeader.magic_number <<
            fileHeader.version_major <<
            fileHeader.version_minor <<
            fileHeader.thiszone <<
            fileHeader.sigfigs <<
            fileHeader.snaplen <<
            fileHeader.network;

fileout.close();
```

So this *should* make a blank capture file, but when I open it in Wireshark I am greeted with:

> The file "hello.pcap" appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet or other data.

I've tried opening the output file in binary mode but that didn't help. I would post this in the WireShark forum, but I think this is user error, not something wrong with WireShark.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`<<` writes the numbers formatted as text (e.g., the five-character string "65535" instead of four bytes representing that number).

To output binary data open the file with `ios::binary` and use `write`. This statement will write the entire header:

```
fileout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fileHeader),
              sizeof fileHeader);
```

The endianness is detected by the reader, so this is portable as long as there's no padding between the struct members.

Note that `thiszone` should be `int32_t`.

Comment: And just in case the op is on a system where it matters, open the file with `ios::binary` as well